# Android - Crash when clicking on RecyclerView when SwipeRefreshLayout loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout` , when I reload my page , when `SwipeRefreshLayout` is loading, I click on the item on the `RecyclerView` and it crashes.

```
04-21 13:14:49.605 25586-25586/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.boxopen.funstack, PID: 25586
                                               java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                   at com.boxopen.funstack.adapter.RecycleBookAdapter$BookViewHolder.onClickLike(RecycleBookAdapter.java:339)
                                                   at com.boxopen.funstack.adapter.RecycleBookAdapter$BookViewHolder.access$100(RecycleBookAdapter.java:64)
                                                   at com.boxopen.funstack.adapter.RecycleBookAdapter$BookViewHolder$2.onDoubleClick(RecycleBookAdapter.java:122)
                                                   at com.boxopen.funstack.listener.DoubleClickListener.onClick(DoubleClickListener.java:36)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

04-21 13:14:49.675 182-1124/? E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 57

Comment: your list have 0 items and you want to access 0 index so it crash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what i understand by your question and log is basically you are clearing the `arraylist` in `onRefresh()` but not notifying the adapter that the list has been cleared.

Please call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after clearing `arraylist`

Comment: omg , just forgot to call    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  , thanks you so much , save my day

Comment: yep , i know, thank you , but i don't have enough reputation to do it

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have cleared your list upon refresh, but the items are still in your recyclerview. You should notify your adapter that the list is empty now.
In your current situation, starting to scroll will probably cause the application to crash as well?!

Answer (score 0):

you should put condition for check the size of (for eg. array, ArrayList ... used by you ) data