# RecyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout crash scroll list

Tags: android

Dears,

I have one RecyclerView (version v7 23.4.0) inside in SwipeRefreshLayout.
If I try scroll down recyclerview while update recycler by SwipeRefreshLayout, something wrong happened, because an interruption occurs with the elements in adapter.

Why Inconsistency??? If I want update the recyclerview, **by default**, recyclerview should be wait the swiperefreshlayout end update! right? How can I solve this? Any tips?

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 7(offset:7).state:60
```

How can stop recyclerview to receive any events while swiperefreshlayout is active?

Comment: what wrong happens please explain

Comment: @ankitagrawal Thanks for your comment, i put exception to explain...

Comment: well becoz you are not notify the adapter as soon as you update the list

Comment: @ankitagrawal not, that is the point! when swiperefreshlayout call the asynctask to update recyclerview, i simple try scrolldown and... booom :-). onPostExecute of AsyncTask i call notifyDataSetChanged(). To clear the state sequence is: swipe top down to activate swiperefresh layout, while asynctask is running by "onRefresh" o scroll down-up to scroll the list...

Answer (score 3):

if you are clearing your list in `onRefresh()` you should notify your adapter 
e.g `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

i have faced the same problem and sloved it that way. credits goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36761376/2968988)