# Indexoutofboundsexception after scrolling up while swipe refresh is refreshing

Tags: android, exception, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception, swiperefreshlayout

[image: swipe to refresh refreshing bug]
Hello! I've got a recyclerview and a swipe to refresh layout . When i swipe down and it starts refreshing when i scroll up while it's still refreshing the app crashes and the log says the thing in the picture. After refrwshing is completed everything works fine until you scroll up while refreshing again . It says indexoutof bounds and position 2. Thanks in advance! :)

Edit 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryNewsBG"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. Also copy and paste the error message here rather than posting a screenshot.

Comment: Next time I will :) But for this time it's almost over , I guess ... It got fixed somehow but what happens now is that the refresh circle disappears when the recyclerview gets to the notifications bar. What could be causing it? :?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it! [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761161/android-crash-when-clicking-on-recyclerview-when-swiperefreshlayout-loading) question describes almost the exact issue I had. Looking for indexoutofbounds didn't work so I managed to locate the problem : It was happening when it was told to clear the list , but I never notified the adapter that the data is refreshed!